# MSGraphContact assign Category works but is not visible

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The online docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=objc) show that categories is a string collection on the class MSGraphContact.  When I use the HTTP post protocol to create a new contact the post succeeds but I don't see any category assigned to the new contact at 'https://outlook.live.com/people/'.

I also don't see any means of assigning a category using browser at that site.

Is this a know limitation?  If so, what value is there in assiging a category to a contact?

Comment: Can you post snippet of the code you are using to create/get categories on the contact? This should work without issues, [example here](https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/blob/43724a68dd7d6627511051c2fb3c3652ed3bd80b/src/Microsoft.Graph.ManagedAPI.FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests/ContactTestDefinition.cs#L78)

Comment: As I said in the original post: "...the post succeeds..."   The issue is visibility using the browser at  'https://outlook.live.com/people/'.  I don't see 'Category' anywhere. Where is this category visible?

Comment: It is up to the client to display it. OWA wont display it, while Outlook will when opening contact window.